# Reversing the Input String in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

The following assembly code should reverse the input string, but it doesn't, it just prints the string data.

```
.model small
.data
    str1 db 13,10,'-Enter String: $'
    str2 db 13,10,'-your reverse string: $'
    t db ? 
    str3 db 100 dup('$')
    str4 db 13,10,'-Your string: $'
.code
main proc
    s:
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
 ;get string   
    mov ah,9
    lea dx,str1
    int 21h

    mov ah,0ah
    lea dx ,str3
    int 21h
  ;get lenght  
    mov bl,str3+1
    add bl,30h
    mov ah,02h
    mov dl,bl
    int 21h
    mov [di],bl
;print entered string
    mov ah,9
    lea dx,str4
    int 21h

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,str3+2
    int 21h
;print reverse string 
    mov ah,9
    lea dx,str2
    int 21h

    mov cx,0   
    lea si,str3+ [di]
    dec si
    mov cl,[si]
    l1:
    mov ah,02h 
    mov dl,[si]
    dec si
    int 21h
    jne l1
main endp
end
```

Comment: You're using `di` in a couple of places, but I don't see you ever initializing `di` to anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
str3 db 100 dup('$')
```

You didn't setup the data structure for the DOS input function. Now it seems to work because the character **$** has a value of 36. Since you display the length of the input as a single character I suggest you write:

```
str3 db 9,0,10 dup('$')
```

When you get the length and display it you should really store the length in DI (not the character)

```
 ;get length  
 mov  bl, str3+1
 mov  dl, bl
 add  dl, 30h
 mov  ah, 02h
 int  21h
 mov  bh, 0
 mov  di, bx
```

Because the text of your input starts at *str3 + 2* you need to change the `LEA`. Better use DI as a loop counter, it already has the length.

```
 lea  si, str3 + 2 + [di]
l1:
 dec  si
 mov  dl, [si]
 mov  ah, 02h 
 int  21h
 dec  di
 jne  l1
```